# CSS positioning at the bottom of an element without using absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a solution for my issue, but I am wondering if there is a better one.

I want to place << and >> navigation buttons at the foot of a section in a web page, so that they are always in the same position, regardless of the contents of the page. Between these buttons, there will be a list of links.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kwmn441/1/) which shows the layout. The relevant section of the HTML used in the jsFiddle is shown below.

```
<div class="foot">
    <div class="back sink">
      <span>&lt;&lt;</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Chapter 1</li>
        <li>Chapter 2</li>
        <li>Chapter 3 which happens to have a long title that wraps to the next line if you make the window narrow</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="next sink">
      <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first CSS I tried is this:

```
.foot {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.foot div {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.sink span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.next span {
    right: 0;
}
```

However, if I use `position: absolute` to place the << and >> arrows at the bottom of their respective `<div>`s, then their parent `<div>`s have no width, and so the text between them is likely to overlap with them, which is not good.

My current solution is to use a flex box and an empty spacer `<div>`, to push the arrows down to the bottom:

```
<div class="foot">
    <div class="back sink">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <span>&lt;&lt;</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Chapter 1</li>
        <li>Chapter 2</li>
        <li>Chapter 3 which happens to have a long title that wraps to the next line if you make the window narrow</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="next sink">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the modified part of the CSS...

```
div.sink {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #fcc;
}
.spacer {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

... and a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr534r1L/) to illustrate the result.

My question is: Is there a more standard solution for this, which will also work on browser that do not support `flex`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS tables.

```css
.foot {
  display: table; /* Table layout */
  table-layout: fixed; /* Use fast and reliable algorithm */
}
.sink, .menu {
  display: table-cell; /* Like `flex-direction: row` for the parent */
  vertical-align: bottom; /* Like `align-items: flex-end` in a column */
}
.menu {
  width: 100%; /* Like `flex-grow: 1` */
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
main {
  height: 100%;
  background: #cfc;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.expand {
  background: #ccf;
  flex: 1;
}
.foot {
  display: table; /* Table layout */
  table-layout: fixed; /* Use fast and reliable algorithm */
}
.sink, .menu {
  display: table-cell; /* Like `flex-direction: row` */
  vertical-align: bottom; /* Like `align-items: flex-end` in a column */
}
.menu {
  width: 100%; /* Like `flex-grow: 1` */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.sink {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="expand"></div>
  <div class="foot">
    <div class="back sink">&lt;&lt;</div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Chapter 1</li>
      <li>Chapter 2</li>
      <li>Chapter 3 which happens to have a long title that wraps to the next line if you make the window narrow</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="next sink">&gt;&gt;</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what you want without using position:absolute or flex.  It relies on you knowing and setting the height of the footer.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr534r1L/1/)

Here's the CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
main {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: #cfc;
}
.expand {
    background: #ccf;
    height:100%;
    margin-bottom:-72px;
}
.foot {
    display:block;
    height:72px;
    background: #cfc;
}
.foot div {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.menu {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:90%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.sink {
    background: #fcc;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:5%;
    height:100%;
    line-height:72px;
}
.back.sink {
    float:left;
}
.next.sink {
    float:right;
}
.spacer {
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not know the height of the footer, and it will change dynamically.